# Is it possible to use a subpart of an array in D3 .data( )

Tags: d3.js

is there a way to use only a subpart of an array
in an D3 .data() command.
For example i have an array with 10 elements from 10 to 100.

```
var myArr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
```

Now i dynamically want to have two boundaries that limit
the values of the array. For example:

```
left:  3
right: 7
which leads to 5 elements:

---> [... 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ...]
```

can i use this five elements in any way without creating
a own array?

```
 selectAll('rect')
 .data(myArr)       // Would select all elements

 selectAll('rect')
 .data(???)     // How to only select the parts 40...80 ?
```

thank you!

Comment: While it does create a new Array, I would use Array.slice for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Specifically, myArr.slice(3, 8) would give yield your desired result.

Comment: I slice fast enough? I will have lots of data points

Comment: You could also use `Array.filter()`